# How to Show Error Messages from OpenTok/PHP

Tags: php, opentok

I'm trying to use the OpenTok PHP SDK but can't seem to get it to work from the start. The code below will work and return the "Success" message. However, if I try to create a new OpenTok object by commenting that line, the message will no longer display.

Is there a way to get some error reporting on what's going on here or other things I should verify?

```
<?php

   require_once 'OpenTok/OpenTok.php';
   require_once 'OpenTok/Session.php';

   //$apiObj = new OpenTok("*******", "********");

   echo "Success";

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should first understand how [PHP does exception handling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

In this case, one quick way to get an error message would be to wrap the code in a try/catch block

```
try {
    require_once 'OpenTok/OpenTok.php';
    require_once 'OpenTok/Session.php';

    $apiObj = new OpenTok("*******", "********");

    echo "Success";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Caught exception: ",  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

More specifically, if you are using the latest OpenTok PHP SDK, the recommended way to load the classes is using a [PSR-0 autoloader](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/), such as the one generated by [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

Comment: Thanks for this! I was planning on using Composer but it turns out I can't for this particular project :/

Comment: No problem! You can definately still load the classes directly, its just a little more work. Hopefully this is enough information to help you solve the issue.

Comment: @Ankur Can you please get me a simple proper working directory of opentok using php sdk. I am having trouble using it. I'hv made opentok app using JS and python SDK. So if possible please help me with PHP.

Comment: @xK0nB1n The sample directory inside the SDK repo contains a couple examples of proper working directories. Start with the HelloWorld example. Clone the repo locally and follow the instructions in the README (https://github.com/opentok/OpenTok-PHP-SDK/tree/master/sample/HelloWorld/README.md).

Comment: @Ankur dear!! I tried those.Now the trouble is with the UI. I can't make the UI better + responsive for example a big subscriber rectangle and a small publisher rectangle inside it. Like skype. A little help would be appreciated.

Comment: @bineetkumar_xK0nB1n take a look at this sample app (https://github.com/opentok/linkkit-php), i think the UI is very similar to what you are looking for.